# Excel 2010 VBA: How to export the current worksheet asking user where to save?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I've a `.xlsm` with a big customized toolbar full of custom tools for handling common situations at work.

The problem is that I need often to save the result and then send to other users, but I don't want to preserve macros / customized toolbars into saved Workbook.

So I'm trying this way: add another workbook, copy/paste the actual worksheet into the new workbook, then I'd like to force opening of save as.

```
'copy entire sheet
Cells.Copy
Range("B2").Select 'just to leave only one cell selected when I return 

'Paste into a new workbook sheet 1
Workbooks.Add
Cells.Select
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
ActiveSheet.Range("B2").Select 'select only one cell
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    .Show
End With
```

The problem is that after I write file name and choose destination folder and press 'Save',  **I got nothing saved ! No file created at all.**

EDIT 1

Probably I'm not clear in my intention. I've a .xlsm that I use to import and manipulate date from other sources. I got a sheet with all data I need (and this contains no formulas). I need to create a new workbook, copy/paste the sheet into this new file, then force opening of save as. At this point **I manually select destination folder, enter file name and choose a file format, and press Save.** I need to be able to **choose these things at runtime**

Actually the problem is that Excel doesn't really save the new file and I don't know why.

Why?

Comment: are you trying to save the workbook with out a macro?

Comment: The new workbook must be saved without macros, yes

Comment: could you not save as an xlsx?

Comment: Yes, I could, but I don't know where you want go. I need to force opening of save as dialog, so I can choose where and in which format, click save, and I've got the processed sheet correctly exported as a new workbook, without any macros/custom tollbars

Comment: I believe what realtebo is getting at is...when he presses save from the saveas dialog box, nothing happens

Comment: @Davesexcel: yes it is. I added clarification, I hope

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give this a go, 1 more time...

```
      Sub SaveASDiBox()
    Dim FlSv As Variant
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    sh.Copy
    MyFile = "YourFileName.xlsx"
    FlSv = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(MyFile, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx)", Title:="Enter your file name")

    If FlSv = False Then Exit Sub

    MyFile = FlSv

    With ActiveWorkbook
        .SaveAs (MyFile), FileFormat:=51, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: `Application.GetSaveAsFilename` My fav :) One suggestion though... You need to use the `FileFormat` in `SaveAs` to avoid any file corruption.

Comment: @ siddharth -Is that not already taken care of in the Saveas dialog box?

Comment: No. Unfortunately not :( `MyFile/FlSv` will only give you the path and the name of the file. Ron has already covered it in one of his [blogs](http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s5/win001.htm) :) Since I was looking at your code again, I noticed one more thing. You may want to handle the `FlSv` if the user chooses to press cancel.

Comment: I also saw one more typo `strFileName`. I have amended the code. If you are not happy with it, feel free to revert the changes :)

Comment: Ah yes, thanks, I was looking to see why the "YourFileName" wasn't showing up.

Comment: You removed the line `If FlSv = False Then Exit Sub` from the edit that I made. Try pressing cancel and see what happens

Comment: Well I didn't remove it, I recopied and pasted my code.

Answer (score 1):

The `FileDialog` class allows the user to select a filename, it doesn't actually do the saving.

After calling `FileDialog.Show` you can access the `FileDialog.SelectedItems` property to get the name(s) of the file(s) selected by the user.

Then call `Workbook.SaveAs` to save the file.